# have an AppleScript Automator service to process all text if no text is selected

Tags: text, osx-lion, applescript

I’m using [nslater's wonderful script](http://gist.github.com/1616556) for counting words and characters in a selected block of text, but I need two enchancements:

1. **have the script available even without text selected.** Currently, when I pull up the list of available Services without a selection, the Service isn’t there (that’s logical, of course, but enhancement #2 would change things).
2. **add a conditional behaviour to the script:** if no text is selected, process *all* text, but if there is a selection, then only process the selected text.

Here is **nslater's** script, which I pasted into Automator (I created the Service by following the steps in his commented instructions):

```
# Word and Character Count service for Mac OS X
#
# Adds a Word and Character Count option to the text selection context menu in all apps
#
# Use Automator.app to create a new service, and then select the Run AppleScript action.
# Paste this code in to the text box, and save as Word and Character Count. Now switch to
# a new app, select some text, and open the context menu to find the new option.

on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"
        set _appname to name of first process whose frontmost is true
    end tell
    set word_count to count words of (input as string)
    set character_count to count characters of (input as string)
    tell application _appname
        display alert "" & word_count & " words, " & character_count & " characters"
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

Comment: That's not how services work. The OS arranges for the service to receive the required input. If the service takes input then it's only available when there's a selection. If the service doesn't take input then there's no reliable way for the service to get the selected text (or all the text).

Comment: Thanks @KenThomases. So if I'm understanding correctly, what I'd need to do is set up a macro with Keyboard Maestro or something to kick off the text selection logic, followed by an invocation of the Service.

Comment: Perhaps. I'm not familiar with Keyboard Maestro, but maybe it allows for direct invocations of scripts, which wouldn't involve the service at all.

Comment: @KenThomases: actually, you can do this if you use the service as a dumb launcher (“No Input”) and use the Accessibility API to retrieve the state of text selection. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10501755/990363) for a way to do just that. About as close to the Text System as you can get in Applescript, I think…

Answer (score 0):

The following AppleScript code will do what you are after:

```
tell application "System Events" to set frontApplication to (first application process whose frontmost is true)
set theText to my getCurrentTextContents(frontApplication)
if theText is not "" then
    set wordCount to count words of theText
    set charCount to count characters of theText
    tell application (name of frontApplication) to display alert "" & wordCount & " words, " & charCount & " characters"
end

on getCurrentTextContents(ofApplication)
    tell application "System Events"
        try -- time-out as some UI elements block, notably system sheets
            with timeout of 5 seconds
                set allElements to entire contents of window 1 of ofApplication
            end timeout
        on error
            return ""
        end try

        repeat with UIelement in allElements
            try –– very large element collections can change before looped through
                if focused of UIelement is true then
                    if attribute "AXSelectedTextRange" of UIelement exists then
                        set {x, y} to value of attribute "AXSelectedTextRange" of UIelement
                        if y ≥ x then
                            return value of attribute "AXSelectedText" of UIelement
                        else
                            return value of UIelement
                        end if
                    else
                        return ""
                    end if
                end if
            on error errorMessage
                log errorMessage
                return ""
            end try
        end repeat
        return ""
    end tell
end getCurrentTextContents
```

If you want to use it in service, you will have to set that service to take “No Input” – as Ken Thomases correctly stated [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489265/augment-a-word-count-applescript-service-with-a-conditional-hotkey-behaviour#comment13558927_10489265), services only process input if there is a selection. In the case of a “No Input” service, you are essentially creating a global (or app-specific, if you restrict the service to an application) launch point for a script. Any other script launcher that does not steal focus from the app it targets will serve as well (and might be faster – Automator services tend to be *veeerrrrryyyyy sssllllooooowwww* on first launch).

Also note the whole thing works through the [Accessibility API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/Accessibility_RoleAttribute_Ref/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007870-Introduction-SW1) (the foundation for GUI scripting) and needs access to the API to be enabled by the user – either by checking “Enable Access for Assistive Devices” in the “Accessibility“ pane of *System Preferences*, or by doing

```
tell application "System Events" to if not UI elements enabled then
    activate
    set UI elements enabled to true
end if
```

it also requires the target application to support the Accessibility API in its text views as defined by Apple (see documentation linked to [above](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/Accessibility_RoleAttribute_Ref/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007870-Introduction-SW1)), and do so correctly. MS Office applications, don’t, for one (they use non-standard views without selection attributes – [thanks @adayzdone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489265/have-an-applescript-automator-service-to-process-all-text-if-no-text-is-selected/10501755#comment13579000_10501755)), and I wouldn’t be surprised if Adobe CS applications didn’t either. Java and AIR applications will probably be problematic, too.

Finally, while I‘m at the *caveat empteor* stage, I’ll add the speed of the script depends directly on the complexity of the UI hierarchy of the targeted application. This is not problem in the case of ordinary apps, but it is definitely in the case of WebKit generated web views – aka *Safari* and co. – as these map the whole DOM to UI elements. Although very laudable in terms of accessibility, this results in a humongous UI hierarchy which will take quite a time to traverse.

Comment: The script worked well in TextEdit. Does it work with other applications? I added --- tell application "Safari"
 activate
 set URL of document 1 to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489265/augment-a-word-count-applescript-service-with-a-conditional-hotkey-behaviour"
 delay 3
end tell --- above the start of the script and did not get any results

Comment: The script, as it is, will work on the **currently frontmost application** and retrieve text contents of the **currently focused field**. If you activate Safari programmatically like you do, no text field will be focused – hence no result. Also note that the UI hierarchy of Safari is huge, as WebKit maps the whole DOM to UI elements (laudable as to accessibility, not too easy on slow old AppleScript). If you select a text field in Safari (the URL bar, say) and just run the service on it, it *will* eventually return the count. Just be patient :).

Comment: @adayzdone: note a text processing application like TextEdit will focus on its document content by default, hence activating and creating a new document will be enough to get a result; however many other apps, like Safari, will not focus on any text field by themselves. Without a focused text field, there is no way for a script to guess what text content you are targeting (in the case of Safari: the URL bar? The search field? The document tab content [which need not be textual]?).

Comment: I simply added a delay 5 and then activated different fields/programs. Safari URL bar works, Word & Excel don't. I assume OP would want body of word doc included in Select All ? For Safari, you can -- set xxx to text of document 1 -- but then you get caught up in app specifics.

Comment: @adayzdone: MS Office apps uses non-standard views for their document area which provide no *AXSelected…* attributes. I already made the caveat that support of the Accessibility API is required, but I’ll expand a bit on that warning.